# Trying to delete each option in Multiple Choice by clicking X next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am making a multiple choice quiz and want to have a button/icon looking like X in front of every option (including being in front of radio button) and when I click on it, it deletes that specific option only.

How would I do that? For example if the options are these. How can I put X in front of every option and by clicking certain X such as one in front of Blue, Blue gets deleted.

It's more of a visual formatting problem. As this happens to be a list, I end up getting my Delete Icon after A. and before radio button for the first option, After B and before Radio button for second option and so on. I want the X icon to be the first thing, even before A, B, C, D etc.

```
   <ol type="A">
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="question" /> Red</li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="question" /> Green</li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="question" /> Blue</li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="question" /> Brown</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I am struggling to make sure the X goes before the radio buttons in the first place. The X is all over the place and I can't visually place it correctly

Comment: @user2626071 if you are using bootstrap you can just put the icon before the input.  Same if you are using an `img`, then you'll want to hide the option that they clicked by passing the `li` html id.

Comment: you can do it the same way we showed you how to delete the whole question.

Comment: So you want each item to start with a letter (A, B, C...), followed by a small image (looking like X), followed by a radio button, followed by some text? I would find that confusing, as a user. But what is the technical difficulty with just putting an `img` element before the `input` element? Is this about coding the functionality (as the title suggests), or visual placement (as your comment suggests)?

Comment: It's more of a visual formatting problem. As this happens to be a list, I end up getting my Delete Icon after A. and before radio button for the first option, After B and before Radio button for second option and so on. I want the X icon to be the first thing, even before A, B, C, D etc.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela No I would like to have the X followed by A followed by radio followed by text but right now I am getting it with A coming before X.

Comment: then you'll need to move to <ul> rather than <ol> and put the A,B,C,D in manually, or though a loop in javascript.  an ordered list is rendered by the browser to force the formatting of the type you specified, if you want a special use case then you'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with something like this:

```
 <ul>
        <li><div class="remove">x</div>A.<input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="question" /> Red</li>
        <li><div class="remove">x</div>B.<input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="question" /> Green</li>
        <li><div class="remove">x</div>C.<input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="question" /> Blue</li>
        <li><div class="remove">x</div>D.<input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="question" /> Brown</li>
    </ul>
```

then use javascript

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {      
      var li =  this.parentNode;
      this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(li)});
}
```

but you'll also need the css:

```
ul li
{
    list-style: none
}
.remove
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAcbm/), i think it does what you're asking

Comment: this question isn't flagged for jQuery, i don't know if the user wants it.  Might just have to make it use normal javascript, good answer though definitely works.

Comment: you're right.. i switched it to straight javascript :)  thanks for pointing that out